# Помощь в создании модуля

Tags: python

Как сделать команду типа.

module.msg("msg")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# File №1 (module.py)
def msg(msg):
    # code

# File №2 
import module
module.msg("Hello world")
```

Файлы должны находится в одной директории